# I' cant display variable of my object in html in Angular

Tags: angular

I have problem with display values of object config in html (I think so).

This is my component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  config: { [key: string]: string | Date } | null = null;

  constructor() {
    setTimeout( () =>{
      this.config = {
        title: 'ToDo-List',
        footer: ' © footer from component',
        date: new Date()
    };}, 500);

  } 
}
```

And this is html part:

```
<div class="container">
  <nav class="row">
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <span class="brand-logo center">{{config.title}}</span>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="row">
    <button class="btn col s2 offset-s10">Add new-task</button>
    <button class="btn col s2 offset-s10">End</button>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <input
      class="col s8"
      type="text"
      placeholder="Dodaj zadanie i datę wykonania"
    />
    <input class="col s2 disabled" type="date" />
    <button class="btn-floating">+</button>
  </div>

  <ul class="collection">
    <li class="collection-item row">
      <span class="col s10">1 Pool - 11.07 </span>
      <div class="col s2 right-align">
        <button class="btn-floating btn-small red">
          <i class="material-icons">remove</i>
        </button>
        <button class="btn-floating btn-small green ml-5">
          <i class="material-icons">check</i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="collection-item row">
      <span class="col done">Clean a bathtub</span>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <h1>No tasks for today :-)</h1>

  <button class="btn red">Clear</button>

  <footer class="page-footer mt-5">
    <div class="footer-copyright">
      <div class="container">
        {{config.date}}
        {{config.footer}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</div>
```

I think that problem is with initialization of object config but I can't figure where.
Each time I get error TS2339: Property 'title' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.

I use Angular 13 and material.

Comment: where are you using `title`. I only see `config.title`? But if you get such an error, it is correct, a variable `title` does not exist in your component.

Comment: You should move your `this.config` initialization into `ngOnInit` and why are you using setTimeout?

Answer (score 0):

At initialize stage your config variable having value null so that's why its giving this error. you can write your variable in html part like below

```
<div class="nav-wrapper">
  <span class="brand-logo center">{{config?.title}}</span>
</div>

<div class="container">
    {{config?.date}}
    {{config?.footer}}
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for a tip, but it's still not working...

Comment: Its working look at this stackblitz code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ve1ghu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: OK. Tank's man, looks like I have to reinstall node.js and angular cli on my pc. Maybe it start to work :)